# Как правильно выделить память для массива char (строки), если предварительно неизвестна его длина

Tags: c

Имеется фрагмент кода:

```
char *dbname = valueOfParam("dbname");
char *dbuser = valueOfParam("dbuser");
char *dbpass = valueOfParam("dbpass");
char *conninfo;
// Then  I try compile new variable like this:
printf("PQconnectdb(\"dbname=%s host=localhost user=%s password=%s\");", dbname, dbuser, dbpass);
// But I need create the variable
sprintf(conninfo, "PQconnectdb(\"dbname=%s host=localhost user=%s password=%s\");", dbname, dbuser, dbpass);
```

Как правильно выделить память для `conninfo`? Ведь без выделения нужного количества памяти код некорректен.

Comment: strlen("PQconnectdb(\"dbname= host=localhost user= password=\");") + strlen(dbname) + strlen(dbuser) + strlen(dbpass) + 1

Comment: `man asprintf` что ли. Причём всем участникам этого уютного чатика.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы воспользовался тем, что [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) при передаче ей размера буфера 0 возвращает количество символов, которое она бы записала (без учета нулевого).

Т.е. примерно так-

```
int len = snprintf(NULL,0,......);
char * buf = malloc(len+1);
```

Comment: Varint work too: 
    char *conninfo = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen("PQconnectdb(\"dbname= host=localhost user= password=\");") + strlen(dbname) + strlen(dbuser) + strlen(dbpass) + 1 ));

Comment: @Irbis Вариант. Но - не универсальный, в отличие от этого. Что делать для `%d`, или еще чего-то? Руками повторять функциональность `sprintf`, вместо чтоб воспользоваться имеющейся?

Comment: `man asprintf` что ли.

Comment: @0andriy Как только вы покажете соответствующее место в стандарте - без вопросов...

Comment: В стандарте, простите, чего? Почитал, пока только в некоторых имплементациях доступна, хорошо.

Comment: *Concerning the return value of snprintf(), SUSv2 and C99  contradict  each  other:  when  snprintf()  is called  with  size=0 then SUSv2 stipulates an unspecified return value less than 1, while C99 allows str to be NULL in this case, and gives the return value (as always) as the number of characters  that  would have  been  written in case the output string has been large enough.  POSIX.1-2001 and later align their specification of snprintf() with C99.*

Comment: Т.е. надо явно указывать `-std=c99`.

Comment: @0andriy Нет, надо в вопросе явно указывать возможность использовать нестандартные вещи. Я с тем же успехом могу сослаться на свою функцию в своей библиотеке - и что, это будет решением? :) Ай, ладно, я уже привык, что если вам дают линованную - вы из принципа будете писать поперек :), а если дадут орфографический словарь - ну, мене страшно представить, что будет написано... Вобщем, с моей стороны дискуссия завершена :)

Comment: Ещё раз, для описанного вами поведения `snprintf()` *необходимо* указывать стандарт не менее C99.